# What is a low level controller for a quadrotor?

Tags: control, quadcopter

I am studying control systems, and I was reading a paper about quadrotors. In the paper it is said that in the platform of the robot it has to be present a low level controller.

But what is a low level controller?

I have tried to search online, but i have not really understood, since I think its definition depends also on the context in which it is used, so I posted the question here in Robotics stack exchange.

In the paper it is also said that the low level controller is prefereable to be open source, so to have the possibility to add capabilities.

So, what is the difference between a low level controller and a high level controller for a quadrotor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers, be it for quadrotors or industrial manipulators or any electromechanical system for that matter, are implemented as hierarchies. Controllers that directly drive the hardware are low-level controllers whereas those that implement logical decision-making are high-level controllers. The terms "high" and "low" are relative. Nested controllers ensure abstraction and code modularity.

In the context of a quadrotor, the controller for the motor driver(s) that actually makes the rotors spin would be a low-level controller, whereas another controller that tells the quadrotor to move forward/backward etc. could be a high-level controller. The low-level controller has abstracted away all the details on how exactly to drive the rotors. All the high-level controller does is *instruct* the low-level controllers that a particular action is desired. It's now the low-level controllers' job to actually spin the rotors in such a way that the quadrotor executes the desired action.

> "in the platform of the robot it has to be present a low level
>   controller"

Think of making your quadrotor execute actions like `ascend(desired_height)` or `translate_forward(distance)`. Great, you've called those functions and have passed the arguments. What then? If the control architecture is implemented as a hierarchy, then these functions would call low-level controllers to actuate the rotors:

```
# high-level controller
ascend(desired_height)
{
    drive_motors(desired_height, 'up')
}

# another high-level controller
translate_forward(distance)
{
    drive_motors(distance, 'forward')
}

# low-level controller
drive_motors(distanceToTarget, direction_to_move_in)
{
    # code that actually drives the motors
}
```

Note that the low-level controller can again call another *lower*-level controller which is even closer to the "metal". Likewise, the high level controllers can be called by an even *higher* level controller, for eg. `go_above_obstacles()` which utilizes `ascend()` and `translate_forward()`. High-level controllers thus are for high-level logic and are generally not concerned with the low-level mechatronic actuation.

Here's another [answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/4676/21531) that might be useful.